# How to use standard library macros with std module in C++23

Tags: c++, c++-modules, c++23

I am currently playing with C++ modules, trying to modernize our company's code C++ base to use modules for the core features. In particular there is the upcoming C++23 `std` module which seems very interesting as a better alternative to precompiled headers.

So I am using Visual Studio 2022 17.5 Preview 2.0, which has a preliminary support for `std` module. By the way, I faced a compiler internal error, a bug that I reported to [Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10080425).

In all our C++ source files, there is now an `import std;` statement, and this works quite well. Every identifier that is supposed to be in `std` namespace seem to be exported as expected. I measured a slight decrease of compilation time compared to the previous use of a precompiled header.

I found out that if you `import std;`, you have a lot of weird compilation errors in you *also* `#include <>` *any* standard C++ header, because Microsoft compiler get confused and complains about redefinition. So I took care of removing all of them.

My problem is that there are a few **macros** that are defined in standard library (mostly in C compatibility library), which are obviously not exported *because C++ modules by design never export macros*.

Our code base use a very limited number of those standard macros, but I think it would be hard to avoid them. Here is the short list of them (unsure it is complete):

- `stdout`
- `errno`
- `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`

For the `va_*` macros, I `#include <stdarg.h>` and it compiles fine on VS 2022, although it breaks the rule I previously mentioned. This is probably because this header has nearly only macros. But for `stdout` and `errno`, I don't know what to so.

Does C++23 specify how to access the important standard macros like `stdout` or `errno` when importing `std` module? Is there a good workaround?

Comment: For global identifiers from C, you might want to import `std.compat`.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep: That won't help for macros.

Comment: `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end` can be wholly replaced by variadic templates and fold espressions; so there's one off the list.

Comment: @Casey. No. Our code base actually declares type safe variadic templates, which then call a private C variadic function for actual implementation. I know this is a bit unusual, but proofed to be **very** powerful.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Our code base is cross platform, although I am currently only playing on Visual Studio. The `std.compat` module is a Microsoft extension. And this does not export macros.

Comment: @prapin: "*The std.compat module is a Microsoft extension.*" [No, it's not.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/library#std.modules-3)

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you for the information, that could be helpful for me.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [C++ working draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/library#std.modules-5):

> A declaration in the standard library denotes the same entity regardless of whether it was made reachable through including a header, importing a header unit, or importing a C++ library module.

So this is probably a bug relative to C++23. Though considering that they only claim partial support for the C++23 modular standard library, it's not surprising.

However, for your specific problem, the issue is mostly solved. Many of these macros come from headers that *only* export the macros. `errno` comes from `<cerrno>`, and `assert` comes from `<cassert>`. `stdout` is a problem because it lives in `<cstdio>` which provides a lot more than just that macro.